# speed up files uploading using aiofiles & aiohttp?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-aiofiles, pytest-aiohttp

I need to speed up files uploading script.
Please, advise how to fix error **Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback**
or there's already known way to do it differently?

```
import asyncio
import aiofiles
import aiohttp


async def upload_file(session, local_path):
    file_data = {
        'me': 'yo'
    }

    async with aiofiles.open(local_path, 'rb') as fp:
        file_content = await fp.read()

        response = session.post('http:/my_url', data=file_content, json=file_data)


async def upload_files(paths):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        await asyncio.gather(*[upload_file(session, **path) for path in paths])


async def main():
    await upload_files([
        {'local_path': '1.txt'},
    ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Await for `ClientSession.post` request:

```
response = await session.post('http:/my_url', data=file_content, json=file_data)
```

Comment: thanks Roman a lot, looks like your suggestion works! may be I also can suggest how to add retries in case of network issues